# Many prompts hidden from sight in the minibuffer when using `EXWM` window manager

Tags: minibuffer, exwm

If I open Emacs 28.0.50 on Ubuntu's Gnome desktop manager (whether full screen or not), I can always see whatever prompts I have to see on the mini-buffer, such as `pass`'s prompt for my passphrase or `pdf-tools` prompt warning that a giving pdf file is very large and asking whether I really want to open it.

Now, if I move to EXWM as my window manager, I can't see these prompts immediately. I have to manually reshape the mini-buffer to increase its size and see the prompt's message.

Other utilities, however, such as `swiper` do resize the mini-buffer alright and I can therefore see all of `swiper`'s results.

For the record, the variable `resize-mini-windows` is correctly set to `grow-only`, so the mini-buffer should adjust its size to whatever is displayed on it.

Has anyone had the same issue and knows whatever might be happening?

Comment: Do you get the same issue with emacs-27.2?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I don't know. But I know of other people with Emacs 28 and no issues in this regard. So I guess something deep down my dotfiles is screwing the right adjustment of the minibuffer to the prompt. My first target was the instructions for having Emacs full screen. But I have commented these out as they are not really needed for using EXWM full screen and I still have the problem in place.